# Used almost all alphabet symbols, what to use for summation indices now?

Tags: symbols

I have already used all the `a,b,c,d,g,i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,t,v,w,\alpha,\beta` symbols, I wonder how to denote summation indices in my paper now? What would you use?

Comment: I don't think this is a TeX/LaTeX problem

Comment: @egreg But where should I ask?

Comment: Package `alphalph` provides ways to extend a limited symbol set.

Comment: @egreg: it _is_ a LaTeX problem

Comment: @Herbert I don't see how it is: asking how to implement some scheme is a TeX problem, asking what scheme to use is not.

Comment: I do not see the (La)TeX problem either. Why don’t you use indices? For example: All “counters” use the variable `c` and are further defined by their index: `c_0`, `c_1`, `c_{\textrm{important}}`, and so on.

Comment: I also agree that it is not a TeX problem but one suggestion is to use different typefaces: `\mathbf{a},\mathrm{b}` and so on...

Comment: By counters, I actually mean the symbols to use in expressions such as `\sum_{i=1}^{N}`, so here I call `i` a counter.

Comment: @Sunny88 I don't want to sound harsh. However, I would like to know what kind of _science_ you do if you need over 30 indices.

Comment: @tohecz I don't need 30 indices :) It is just that those other symbols are already used for things unrelated to indices. And now that I need to do indices I need to find some notation for it. And I can't use just any free symbol, like `e` or `f`, because indices with this symbols look very strange. I am looking for something that I can use, and people will not say "I have never seen this symbol used for indices".

Comment: @Sunny88 In `\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i}`, `i` is a "dummy index"; any other name won't change the meaning of the expression. There's no need to use different variables for each summation, unless they are nested and it's difficult to imagine an expression with more than five or six nested summations.

Comment: @Sunny88 people _will_ say it with anything other than latin or greek alphabet, and even with many greek letters they'll be confused (e.g. `\pi,\sigma` as summation indiced usually mean permutations). Open [`symbols_a4`](http://www.math.ku.dk/~holm/download/symbols-a4.pdf) and use whatever symbol you want, e.g. `\clubsuit`, `\diamondsuit`, `\spadesuit` and `\heartsuit`.

Comment: I suggest that you save `i`, `j` and `k` for the dummy indices in summations. As @egreg notes, they can be reused over and over again. I also wonder, along with @tohecz, about using up the whole alphabet for variable names. Consider doing what computer scientists do and use whole words for names - words that help the reader with the meanings of the variables.

Comment: Shortly saying, indices are local.

Comment: @Sunny88 May be you could include a part of your code so that we could correct/solve it.